# How can I tally the number of times each letter occurred in a string in a list

Tags: python

Word Problem:

Write and test a function that given a string of characters, returns a list with a tally (total number) of each individual character of the alphabet (A through Z) found in the string, ignoring case. The first element in the returned list is the tally for 'A'; the second element is the tally for 'B'; etc.

Function Definition

```
def countChars(s: str) -> list:
```

Example Input:

```html
a = 'aBBcccDDDD'
print(countChars(a))
```

Example Output:

```html
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So far, I created a variable with all of the letters in a alphabet, and empty list for the result, a tally that will count the number occurrences and a variable that will keep track what letter I'm on. I decided to put it in a while loop to loop through every letter in the alphabet (A-Z) and for each letter, I made it so that it will loop through every character in that string. The problem is, my code can't run and I'm not sure if its going to work

```html
def countChars(s: str) -> list:
    tally = 0
    result = []
    alphabet = 1
    letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    while alphabet != 27:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            lower = s.lower()
            if letter[i] in lower[i]:
                tally +=1
                result.append[tally]
            else:
                result.append[0]
        alphabet +=1
    return result

a = 'aBBcccDDDD'
print(countChars(a))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What actually is your **question**? Please read [ask]. (Also, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and don't use snippets for Python code - only Javascript examples are runnable.) What exactly does "my code can't run and I'm not sure if its going to work" mean? **What happens** when you try to run the code? **What should happen instead**, and how is that different? **Why** aren't you sure, and what are you talking about where you say "going to" work - I thought you said that you already tried it and it doesn't?

Comment: Are you looking for help with fixing your approach to the problem? Or do you just want to know how to solve it using normal tools? (I.e., is this [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822) where you are being expected to implement an algorithm, or is it a real-world problem where you want a simple and practical way to do it?) We aren't a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service; if you are trying to figure out a problem, you should try by yourself first to check what the code actually does vs. what you want it to do, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your loop by utilizing [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
def count_chars(s: str) -> list[int]:
    counts = [0] * 26
    for ch in s:
        if ch.isalpha():
             counts[ord(ch.lower()) - ord('a')] += 1
    return counts


def main() -> None:
    print(f'{count_chars("aBBcccDDDD") = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
count_chars("aBBcccDDDD") = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```